# Google Sheets: allow either of two cells to be edited and the other to update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to get around circular problems here. I want to create a system where someone can check either of two boxes, and the other one will automatically sync with the one checked. Is this possible?

Comment: While it is clear in your mind what you want your question is quite vague. If you provide an example of what you want to see happen that would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want, on google sheets, for there to be two check boxes on separate sheets. If someone checks the first button true, I would like for the other button to show as true as well, and vice versa.

Comment: For that you will need to use JavaScript for Google Sheets. You could also check out Apps Script at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Have a look at Triggers here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers . The onEdit() function allows you to notice a change on one sheet and change it on another sheet. This is more for changes to data in cells to keep data in sync, but you can also apply a similar approach to checkboxes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

See the [synchronizeRanges_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/94068154?msgid=94123051) script for sample code.